# Github Action in limbo after setting required statuses

Tags: github, github-actions

I have 3 workflows I'm using for my Github repo that I'm trying to get to work, but keep falling into a stalemate after one of the actions completes.

I have the following actions:

- markdown linter
- image compressor
- publish to gh-pages

I also have the `markdown linter` and the `image compressor` as required statuses since I don't want ill-formatted or uncompressed images to be pushed to the live Github pages.

Unfortunately, what I'm encountering at the moment is, the linter checks and passes, then the image compressor runs and adds to the current PR the updated images. But then because its updated the linter is sitting idle with no way to merge.

The script:

```yaml
name: Safe merging workflow
on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  job1:
    name: "Markdown Linter"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Markdown Lint
        uses: ruzickap/action-my-markdown-linter@v1
  job2:
    name: "Image Compression"
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Compress Images
        uses: calibreapp/image-actions@main
        with:
          githubToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Is there any way I can run this so:

1. if the linter passes, the images are compressed, and then the user can merge
2. if the linter passes, and there are no images to compress then the user can merge
3. if the linter fails, the images don't get compressed

Comment: Is your problem that the no new workflow is triggered after the compressed images are pushed? Why do you need to push the compressed images back to the repository? Couldn't you just directly publish your page with the images compressed on the fly?

Comment: @rethab it pushes back to the PR automatically part of the action.. is there a way to not do that, and have it part of the PR when merged?

Comment: You could have a separate job that runs on `push: main`..

Comment: The `main` branch is protected from pushes. So anything that needs to be done is via a PR to protect from unauthorised people from committing to the main branch, and forcing the review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-run the linter every time your PR is synchronized with new commits. The following step is the next step after you've already committed the compressed image.

```
name: Safe merging workflow
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize

jobs:
  job1:
    name: "Markdown Linter"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Markdown Lint
        uses: ruzickap/action-my-markdown-linter@v1
  job2:
    name: "Image Compression"
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Compress Images
        uses: calibreapp/image-actions@main
        with:
          githubToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```